# How I can inject dependeny into hub constructor in signalR core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working in asp.net signal core under asp.net core 2.2, i want to inject dependency in hub constructor, how i can do this?
I made it generic,to pass parameter on constructor.

**My Hub:**

```
 public class IntegratedHUB : Hub<IIntegratedHubClient>
    {
        private readonly AuthorizeConnection _authorizeConnection = new AuthorizeConnection();
        private readonly ISignalRIdentity _signalRIdentity;
        private readonly IVideoService _videoService;
        public IntegratedHUB(ISignalRIdentity signalrIdentity, IVideoService videoService)
        {
            _signalRIdentity = signalrIdentity;
            _videoService = videoService;
        }
}
```

**My Start up class**

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var _unitofWork = new UnitOfWork(new DbFactory());
            var _SignalrIdentity = new SignalRIdentity(_unitofWork, new UnitOfWork(new DbFactory()));
            var _videoService = new VideoService(_unitofWork, new UnitOfWork(new DbFactory()));
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)/*WithOrigins("https://localhost:44381")*/
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
            services.AddTransient<IntegratedHUB, IntegratedHUB>(); // how  i change it?
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseSignalR(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapHub<IntegratedHUB>("/integratedHUB");
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

How i can inject dependency in hub constructor?

Comment: I believe dependency injection should already work for a Hub, as long as the MapHub method is invoked in Configure(). Since you already did that, it should work. Are there any specific errors you're getting? Sidenote: I also believe the `services.AddTransient<IntegratedHUB, IntegratedHUB>()` call is not necessary.

Comment: By the way, if you want to use your Hub you should inject `IHubContext<IntegratedHUB>`, instead of `IntegratedHUB` directly. Maybe that's where it goes wrong? See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: You need to add ISignalRIdentity and IVideoService to DI. Also, remove the AddTransient<IntegratedHUB, IntegratedHUB>() call, it's not needed.